# how to access bearer token in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt

I'm trying to get the current user info using jwt token after successfully login, the token is saved in the browser but each time i send the request i get an error

token i get in my application tab on my console

```
token:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2MjM4NzA4ZDc2ZDVkMDJmZWMwNGRiZDEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDgwODI3MTV9.xvFdGR8skZntTIdlo9aSCx90315rSoUxct_VIR9cf6Q
```

error i get in my console when i'm on the user route

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Failed to authenticate"
}
```

my script tag to get the current user info

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App"
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/user", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer ${token}",
          token: localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

backend route for authentication

```
router.get("/auth/user", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  
    try {
      let foundUser = await User.findOne({
        _id: req.decoded._id
      }).populate(
        "address"
      );
      if (foundUser) {
        res.json({
          success: true,
          user: foundUser
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: err.message
      });
    }
  });
```

jwt middleware to verify the token

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  let token = req.headers["x-access-token"] || req.headers["authorization"];
  let checkBearer = "Bearer ";

  if (token) {
    if (token.startsWith(checkBearer)) {
      token = token.slice(checkBearer.length, token.length);
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "Failed to authenticate"
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;

        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: "No token Provided"
    });
  }
};
```

i dont get why i'm getting an error when my token is saved in my local storage

Answer (score 0):

you should see your token in console.

if you dont see, you did not save correctly. you must check your save method.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App"
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let token=localStorage.getItem("token");
   console.log(token);
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/user", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          token: token
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

and i arranged your middleware method. for get token, you can split space charecter and take last index.

```
const autheticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    const token = authHeader?.split(' ')[1];
    if (token === null) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "Failed to authenticate"
        });

    }
    JWT.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return  res.json({
          success: false,
          message: "Failed to authenticate"
        });
        }
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
    });
}
```

Comment: getting an error with the new middleware  .......                                                            
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Comment: did you export method `module.exports=autheticateToken `

Comment: yes  this show me error in vs code   const token = authHeader?.split(' ')[1];